# Google Maps Api v3 - Legend Duplication

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, duplicates, domdocument, klipfolio

I have embed a google maps in Klipfolio,
however the legend's items are duplicating themselves from time to time when you refresh the page.
[screenshot of the legend duplicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXKMO.png) and [codes](https://jsfiddle.net/sedgod/kbrrzx9c/)

the body includes the 2 tags for the map canvas and the legend

```
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <div id="legend"></div>
```

and this is how i populate the legend as per google maps api documentation in the script.

```
// setting the legend
var iconBase = 'https://i.imgur.com/';
var icons = {
    mine_site: {
       name: 'Mine Site',
       icon: iconBase + 'JCSVR5C.png'
    },
    mine_depot: {
       name: 'Mine Depot',
       icon: iconBase + 'XkWP909.png'
    },
    warehouse: {
       name: 'Exporter Warehouse',
       icon: iconBase + 'W7u6wR3.png'
   }
};

var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
for (var key in icons) {
   var type = icons[key];
   var name = type.name;
   var icon = type.icon;
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + icon + '"> ' + name;
   legend.appendChild(div);
}

map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(legend);
```

I even used a counter to append to the legend only for a number of times equal to the length of the legend items, but to no avail.

I am wondering if it might not be due to some compatibility with klipfolio. Has anyone met this issue?
Is there something I am doing wrong? Or how can I be sure that it is because of the compatibility issue?
Meanwhile, I do not get any warning or errors when those duplicates occur.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  [Fiddle containing the posted code (only one set of icons)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/mk7usm1v/)

Comment: @geocodezip Thank you for the instructions.
I have given an example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sedgod/kbrrzx9c/), but the duplications are not appearing. I am thinking that the environment of [klipfolio](https://www.klipfolio.com/) is playing a big part in it.

Comment: Then you haven't provided a complete example.  That should help you find where the issue is.  But until you can provide a [mcve] it is hard to help.

Comment: The issue is that i cant replicate klipfolio's environment in jsfiddle.

Comment: I have come across some links [question](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4487), [answer](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/pages/) that indicate that it is being caused by js code document.createElement() that might duplicate things when the content is not inside data-role="page".
Unfortunately, it is not working even on my side.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever else that will meet this error, I solved this by a work-around. Just remove values that repeat themselves by using their css class. An example can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sedgod/yLzuqomd/).

```
<html>
<div class = "test">Window</div>
<div class = "test">Table</div>
<div class = "test">Chaise</div>
<div class = "test">Window</div>
<div class = "test">Chaise</div>
</html>
<script>
$('.test').each(function () {
  $('.test:contains("' + $(this).text() + '"):gt(0)').remove();  
});
</script>
```

Refer to the previous comments I made about js making duplicates when it is being loaded from the body.