# Duplicated images and text in google maps legend

Tags: google-maps

I built this Google Maps with a legend. Please see the below code.
The elements in the legend are duplicated sometimes on the first load and other times on page refresh, on all devices.
I saw also similar problems on Stackoverflow ([see there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48221770/google-maps-api-v3-legend-duplication)) but none found the solution. I remove some extra part of the code.

```
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 8,
                center: centerCords
            });
var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
        for (var key in icones) {
          var type = icones[key];
          var name = type.name;
          var icon = type.icon;
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + icon + '"> ' + name;
          legend.appendChild(div);
        }
addMarkerInfo();
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM].push(legend);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered through this bug in the IssueTracker : https://issuetracker.google.com/131115682

I have noticed that you are calling the initMap() function twice apart from your Maps Javascript callback:

1st :

```
 <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
```

2nd :

```
window.onload = function () {
    initMap();
};
```

I tried to remove the 2nd call, and the legends no longer has duplicates.